# Firemonkey CUDA/OpenCL

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3, firemonkey-fm2

On the Embarcadero website it says it supports this but I haven't seen no demos or examples that come with Delphi. So if this is a farce which it indeed looks like then I bet we will have to wait till XE9 for a proper CUDA/OpenCL support.

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41688

> **Q:** Does FireMonkey allow for use of the GPU for high performance
>   computing (e.g. CUDA or OpenCL)?
>
> **A:** It can, yes.

So how to do basic CUDA/OpenCL computation with Firemonkey?

Comment: Further down: *Q: Does FireMonkey have a capability like OpenCL to use the GPU for math operations A: Not in this release.* isn't GPU programming orthogonal to FMX? Why does it have to be part of FMX?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It was planed for GLScene way back when.. before Firemonkey even existed..

Comment: Hehe, well, I also "allow" you to use CUDA or OpenCL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allowed to use CUDA or OpenCL with FireMonkey.

I mean, FireMonkey is not disabling OpenCL/CUDA when it uses DirectX/OpenGL for rendering.

This is the meaning of the FAQ.

Pure truth. No lie.

(I admit I went to a jesuit university)
:)

So you need an OpenCL/CUDA library and compiler. I suspect you can use [this open source project](https://code.google.com/p/delphi-opencl/), or [this one](https://code.google.com/p/pascuda/), or write an external CUDA dll with another compiler, more integrated to the CUDA/OpenCL programming. Some [sample code here](https://plus.google.com/110131086673878874356/posts/eWcipK16MV7).

Comment: Why -1, oh proud anonymous down-voter? Because of the reference to Jesuits? Even the current pope would have laugh on it. :)